# why is file drag and drop disabling draggable elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, file-upload, drag-and-drop

Hello stack overflow community!

I am writing a script to make simple drag and drop able document maker. I wrote all my current code by myself, but I had no clue how to enable dragging of desktop files to the document. Here is the code I have written so far(sorry for the messed up indenting, the codeblock feature messed it up):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
     #main { position:absolute; top:10px; left:50%; margin-left:-450px; width:900px; height:900px; border:dashed 1px lightgrey; }
     #trash { margin-top:10px; width:200px; height:200px; border:dotted 4px black; position:absolute; top:0px; left:5px; }
     #new { width:200px; height:200px; border:dotted 5px black; }
     .new { float:right; }
     .drag { float:left; resize:both; overflow:hidden; height:110px; width:110px; }
     .square { background-color:none; width:10px; height:10px; float:left; }
     .drag * { resize:none; width:100px; height:100px }
     .block { background-color:red; }
      </style>

      <script src="jq/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="jq/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <script>
     var blockcolors = ["red","blue","green","yellow","white","black","lightgrey","lightblue"];
     var color = 1;
     var id = 2;
     function drag(ev)
     {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
     }

     function drop(ev)
     {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text")));
     }
     function droptrash(ev)
     {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $("#"+ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text")).remove();
     }
     function change(div)
     {
        var divw=parseInt(div.style.width);
        var divh=parseInt(div.style.height);
        var imgw=divw-10;
        var imgh=divh-10;
        div.children[0].style.width=imgw;
        div.children[0].style.height=imgh;
        div.style.border="dotted 3px grey";
     }
     function makeGrid()
     {
        var main = $("#main");
        for (var i = 0; i < 8100; i++)
        {
           var square = document.createElement('div');
           square.setAttribute('class', 'square');
           square.ondragover = function(event) { event.preventDefault(); };
           square.ondrop = function(event) { drop(event); };
           main.prepend(square);
        }
     }
     function additem() {
       var newbox = document.getElementById("new");
       newbox.innerHTML = '<div id="div'+id+'" class="drag" onmouseout="this.style.border=0" draggable="true" ' +
                 'ondragstart="drag(event)" onmousemove="change(this)"></div>';
       div = document.getElementById("div"+id);
       div.innerHTML = $("#newtype").val();
       id+=1;
     }
     function blockcolor(block) {
        block.style.backgroundColor = blockcolors[color];
        if (color == blockcolors.length-1)
           color = 0;
        color++;
     }
      </script>
   </head>   
   <body onload="makeGrid()" class="new">
      <div id="new" class="new"></div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      <select id="newtype" class="new">
     <option value="<img draggable='false' src='glider.jpg'/>">Image</option>
     <option value="<textarea></textarea>">Text box</option>
     <option value="<div onclick='blockcolor(this)' class='block'></div>">Block</option>
      </select>
      <button onclick="additem()" class="new">add an item</button>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      <center>
     <div style="clear:both"></div>
     <div ID="main" overflow="auto">
     </div>
      </center>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      <div id="trash" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="droptrash(event)" overflow="auto"><big>Trash</big></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

this works, but it has no functionality for dragging in files. i wanted to add this code i found online which works by itself:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#drop { min-height: 150px; width: 250px; border: 1px solid blue; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; }
</style>
<script>
if(window.FileReader) { 
 var drop; 
 addEventHandler(window, 'load', function() {
    drop   = document.getElementById('drop');
    var list   = document.getElementById('list');
    
    function cancel(e) {
      if (e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); }
      return false;
    }
  
    // Tells the browser that we *can* drop on this target
    addEventHandler(drop, 'dragover', cancel);
    addEventHandler(drop, 'dragenter', cancel);

addEventHandler(drop, 'drop', function (e) {
  e = e || window.event; // get window.event if e argument missing (in IE)   
  if (e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } // stops the browser from redirecting off to the image.

  var dt    = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;
  for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();
      
    //attach event handlers here...
   
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
addEventHandler(reader, 'loadend', function(e, file) {
    var bin           = this.result; 
    var img = document.createElement("img"); 
    img.file = file;   
    img.src = bin;
    drop.innerHTML = "";
    drop.appendChild(img);
}.bindToEventHandler(file));
  }
  return false;
});
Function.prototype.bindToEventHandler = function bindToEventHandler() {
  var handler = this;
  var boundParameters = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  //create closure
  return function(e) {
      e = e || window.event; // get window.event if e argument missing (in IE)   
      boundParameters.unshift(e);
      handler.apply(this, boundParameters);
  }
};
  });
} else { 
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Your browser does not support the HTML5 FileReader.';
}
function addEventHandler(obj, evt, handler) {
    if(obj.addEventListener) {
        // W3C method
        obj.addEventListener(evt, handler, false);
    } else if(obj.attachEvent) {
        // IE method.
        obj.attachEvent('on'+evt, handler);
    } else {
        // Old school method.
        obj['on'+evt] = handler;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <DIV id="drop"></DIV>
  <DIV id="list"></DIV>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is combining them. The second script messes up all drag and drop functionality for the whole thing. I would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is some minor change in the file drop script. Just rename the variable "drop" to "dropElement"( or any other name then "drop"), as it was conflicting with the function name "drop" in first script. so here is your second script.

```
<script>
if(window.FileReader) { 
 var dropElement; 
 addEventHandler(window, 'load', function() {
    dropElement   = document.getElementById('drop');
    var list   = document.getElementById('list');

    function cancel(e) {
      if (e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); }
      return false;
    }

    // Tells the browser that we *can* drop on this target
    addEventHandler(dropElement, 'dragover', cancel);
    addEventHandler(dropElement, 'dragenter', cancel);

addEventHandler(dropElement, 'drop', function (e) {
  e = e || window.event; // get window.event if e argument missing (in IE)   
  if (e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } // stops the browser from redirecting off to the image.

  var dt    = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;
  for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    //attach event handlers here...

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
addEventHandler(reader, 'loadend', function(e, file) {
    var bin           = this.result; 
    var img = document.createElement("img"); 
    img.file = file;   
    img.src = bin;
    dropElement.innerHTML = "";
    dropElement.appendChild(img);
}.bindToEventHandler(file));
  }
  return false;
});
Function.prototype.bindToEventHandler = function bindToEventHandler() {
  var handler = this;
  var boundParameters = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  //create closure
  return function(e) {
      e = e || window.event; // get window.event if e argument missing (in IE)   
      boundParameters.unshift(e);
      handler.apply(this, boundParameters);
  }
};
  });
} else { 
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Your browser does not support the HTML5 FileReader.';
}
function addEventHandler(obj, evt, handler) {
    if(obj.addEventListener) {
        // W3C method
        obj.addEventListener(evt, handler, false);
    } else if(obj.attachEvent) {
        // IE method.
        obj.attachEvent('on'+evt, handler);
    } else {
        // Old school method.
        obj['on'+evt] = handler;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! i cannot express my gratitude. i have spent the last two weeks trying to fix that. thank you.